# How to hover over some link and wait for popup to appear. (WatiN)

Tags: c#, watin

I need to hover over a link to make popup to appear. I used MouseEnter() function but it lasts just milliseconds and i need approx 3 seconds of hovering to make popup to appear. So how can i make my hovering last for 3 or 5 seconds? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Tooltip Control or you did a Custom Pop Up Control ?

Comment: I need to see some Code while Displaying the Popup ,and how did you achieved it ,did you create a Custom Pop Form or Control or are you using Already Built In .NET Tooltip Control

Comment: I'm using WatiN. Here is common code just for example: FireFox browser = new FireFox("url"); browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("some_url")).MouseEnter(); This will just highlight my link for approx 0.1 sec and will not cause tooltip to appear. So i need this command to last longer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried firing the onmouseover event? Something like:

```
  browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("some_url")).FireEvent("onmouseover");
```

.

if that doesn't work, have you tried calling the Javascript method explicitly?  Like:

```
   browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("some_url")).Eval("javascript_method_call_code");
```